# Avoiding the div movement on browser resizing

Tags: html, css

Sir,
 there is a parent div which contain another div inside it. I have placed it at center of window about 200px below from top. But when i resize the browser whole div get move accordingly. I want that div should not move on browser resizing.

**below is the complete page :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#animationblockcontainer{position:absolute;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; width:1033px;height:300px;border:solid 0px red;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:200px; min-width:1033px;}
.leftpanel1 {
    width: 280px;
    height: 270px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 z-index:100;
 top:0;
  }
  .rightpanel1 {
    width: 682px;
    height: 270px;
    background: #ccc;
 position:absolute;
 float:right;z-index:100;top:0;right:0;
  }
 
.stylecell{border:solid 2px #1d80d5; background:#fff;}
.stylepad{padding:15px;}
.boldtext{font-family:"trebuchet MS"; font-size:25px; font-weight:700; color:#003a6c; line-height:1.1;}
.normaltext{font-family:"trebuchet MS";font-size:20px; line-height:1.1;color:#01386e;}

 </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#474747">
  <div id="animationblockcontainer">
                      <div id="toggle1" class="leftpanel1 stylecell stylepad">Image Here</div><div id="toggle2" class="rightpanel1 stylecell stylepad"><span class="boldtext">bolded text bolded text bolded text bolded textbolded text bolded text</span><br/>
        <span class="nomraltext">normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text </span>
        </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't know where your problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/xokhyn8s/

Comment: Remove `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` from `#animationblockcontainer`

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You want to keep that container in Middle vertically or horizontally? Its already horizontally centered.

Comment: on resizing browser window animationblockcontainer get shifted accordingly, i would want to avoid that .. On resizing the browser window the div should remain at same position.